# Str_replace don't work with hex

Tags: php

Why didn't work this code. I need to convert `hex` to `int` in big text file.
I don't know how fix it.

```
//array with hex +9999 length
$number1 = ["90.5E1","11.46E2" "81.60E1","0x216","0xffff","8.05E2","33.30E1","0x21C"];
//file with hex +9999 length
$file = '90.5E1 0x216 8.05E2 8.05E2';

foreach ($number1 as $value) {
    $int = (int)$value;
    $file = str_replace($value,$int,$file);
}

return $file;
```

Comment: Post the result of code

Comment: Actually - I think the replace is working, it's just the values you want to replace them with are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have a parse error in your array you are missing a comma!

```
//array with hex +9999 length
$number1 = ["90.5E1","11.46E2", "81.60E1","0x216","0xffff","8.05E2","33.30E1","0x21C"];
//file with hex +9999 length
$file = '90.5E1 0x216 8.05E2 8.05E2';

foreach ($number1 as $value) {
    $int = (int)$value;
    $file = str_replace($value,$int,$file);
}

echo $file;
```

returns: `905 0 805 805`

Comment: its example im writed, problem with "search", not with replace or array

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string like `"0xFF"` to hex using `intval("0xFF", 0)`. The `0` makes it detect the `0x` prefix and automatically convert from hex.

```
//array with hex +9999 length
$number1 = ["90.5E1","11.46E2","81.60E1","0x216","0xffff","8.05E2","33.30E1","0x21C"];
//file with hex +9999 length
$file = '90.5E1 0x216 8.05E2 8.05E2';

foreach ($number1 as $value) {
    if (substr($value, 0, 2) == '0x')
        $int = intval($value, 0);
    else
        $int = (int)$value;
    $file = str_replace($value,$int,$file);
}

echo $file;
```

Outputs: `905 534 805 805`

**EDIT:**

If you want to replace the values without using `$number1`, you could split the file by spaces and replace each of the values:

```
$file = '90.5E1 0x216 8.05E2 8.05E2';

$file = preg_replace_callback('/([^ ]+)/', function ($matches) {
  $value = $matches[0];
  if (substr($value, 0, 2) == '0x')
    return intval($value, 0);
  else
    return (int)$value;
}, $file);

echo $file;
```

Outputs: `905 534 805 805`

Comment: problem not with "replace", problem with find `str_replace($value,'hello_wrld',$file);`

Comment: Perhaps update your question with "expected input" and "expected output". Do you want to perform the replacement without using `$number1`?